# How to attach spotlight found document to mail message with os x yosemite?

Tags: macos, email, spotlight

In my mail message I want to attach an image. I located the image via spotlight and now I want to attach it to my mail message (plain apple mail). The image file is somewhere deep in my folderstructure where I don't want to go now. How can I achieve this with as less effort as possible?

Comment: I've used the find in the download pop up of 'attach'.

Comment: You can drag and drop the file to Your Mail message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers suggest, you can simply drag and drop into your mail message.  However, I found that this is not always the behavior that I want.  Sometimes I want to see the file in the context of its own folder, or get additional files around it.

Holding down the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> key, while double-clicking on the Spotlight result, will open the containing folder of your image (or any file) in the Finder.  I use this function *all the time*.

**As a bonus**, just holding the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> key will show you the path of the file underneath its Preview, as illustrated in the following screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As like in many other places in OS X, items in Spotlight Search are draggable.

So You can drag and drop the file You want straight from Spotlight to the mail message.